# Bazel Build: @nccl_archive//:nccl: could not resolve label 'ws2_32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I'm installing tensorflow serving from source.

Required libraries that I installed to run `tensorflow-serving` from source:

- `bazel-0.7.0-windows-x86_64.exe` is downloaded from [github-bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) and stored as `C:\Bazel\bazel.exe`. `C:\Bazel\bazel.exe` is in environment variable `PATH`
- `grpcio==1.7.0` by `pip install grpcio`
- msys2 - `msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe`
- python - `python 3.5.2` from `Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)`
- `BAZEL_VC` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC`
- `BAZEL_VS` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`

Initially I installed `Visual Studio Community 2017` and `Windows SDK` for that, then I got `could not resolve label 'ws2_32.lib'.`

I thought, maybe `ws2_32.lib` comes with only 2015 edition. So I went ahead and installed `Visual Studio 2015`. As `BAZEL_VC` and `BAZEL_VS` are set, I didn't bother to uninstall `Visual Studio Community 2017`. After installing `Windows SDK`, I came to know that `ws2_32.lib` is present inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib`. Actually the file name is `WS2_32.lib`. I'm assuming they are the same. But still I'm getting the same error. I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is the output of `bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/...`

```
DEBUG: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl:15:1: hi dude %s PYTHON_BIN_PATH
____Loading package: tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata
DEBUG: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/pkg/pkg.bzl:197:9: @//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server_tar: you provided a non dictionary to the pkg_tar `files` attribute. This attribute was renamed to `srcs`. Consider renaming it in your BUILD file.
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
____Loading package: @local_config_xcode//
____Loading package: @local_config_cc//
____Loading package: @local_jdk//
____Loading complete.  Analyzing...
____Loading package: @protobuf_archive//
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//platforms
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//src
____Loading package: @boringssl//
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/coverage
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/genrule
____Loading package: @six_archive//
____Loading package: @local_config_cuda//cuda
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/c/eager
____Loading package: @swig//
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//third_party/py/numpy
____Loading package: @local_config_python//
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/grappler/utils
____Loading package: @local_config_sycl//sycl
____Loading package: @com_googlesource_code_re2//
____Loading package: @eigen_archive//
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/lib/db
____Loading package: @lmdb//
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1799:1: in includes attribute of cc_library rule @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../../../external/nsync/public' resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its package 'external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:1104:30.
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/compiler/xla
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:515:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle_lite': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:600:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle_lite': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:515:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature_lite': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:600:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature_lite': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:623:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regressor_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/factorization/kernels
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:141:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_factory_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_factory_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:61:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:bundle_factory_util_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:bundle_factory_util_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:229:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_source_adapter_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_source_adapter_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
____Loading package: @jsoncpp_git//
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//third_party/hadoop
____Loading package: @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/factorization
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:562:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classification_service: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classification_service' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:450:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:get_model_metadata_impl_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:get_model_metadata_impl_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:646:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:multi_inference: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:multi_inference' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:486:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:432:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:get_model_metadata_impl: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:get_model_metadata_impl' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:581:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regression_service: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regression_service' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:412:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:207:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_source_adapter: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_source_adapter' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:120:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_factory: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_factory' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:538:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classifier_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/batching/BUILD:72:1: in cc_test rule //tensorflow_serving/batching:batching_session_test: target '//tensorflow_serving/batching:batching_session_test' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:session_bundle': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:412:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:predict_impl' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:581:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regression_service: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:regression_service' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
WARNING: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/BUILD:562:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classification_service: target '//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:classification_service' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately..
____Loading package: @pcre//
____Loading package: @nccl_archive//
ERROR: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/nccl_archive/BUILD:46:16: in linkopts attribute of cc_library rule @nccl_archive//:nccl: could not resolve label 'ws2_32.lib'.
ERROR: C:/users/abhisek.panigrahi/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_abhisek.panigrahi/9tglboge/external/nccl_archive/BUILD:46:16: in linkopts attribute of cc_library rule @nccl_archive//:nccl: could not resolve label 'ws2_32.lib'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server_deb' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@nccl_archive//:nccl' failed; build aborted.
____Elapsed time: 7.328s
```

Output of `git log -1` when inside root-directory-of-tensorflow-serving.

```
commit a82e7d060dad08b911be945fa1732a2a71a73771 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Fred Reiss <frreiss@us.ibm.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 13 10:26:46 2017 -0800

    Sync code example in docs with original (#654)
```

I've done `git submodule update`.

Answer (score 1):

`could not resolve label 'ws2_32.lib'` is actually an error reported by Bazel instead of MSVC compiler. This is caused by a wrong use of linkopts in [nccl.BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/nccl.BUILD#L58). I sent [#14790](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14790) to fix it.

But unfortunately, there still isn't a Windows build for tensorflow_serving. Mainly because we hit the Windows long path issue. I filed [this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4149) to track this problem.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue ? Maybe putting the file in a place so it can find it.